# Websphere Liberty Profile using Maven - watching for changes

Tags: maven, websphere-liberty

I'm checking the **Websphere Liberty Profile** maven plugin that you can find [here](https://github.com/WASdev/ci.maven).

By playing quickly with the provided goals, I'm unable to find an easy way to configure my maven plugins in order to have a *"watch for changes"* functionality.

The idea is to ease the use by developers, and having any changes made on the resources being reflected on the app deployed on the liberty server instance running.

I'm currently using the goals : `mvn liberty:run-server and liberty:deploy`

Comment: Have you considered raising an issue in github?

Comment: I have, but this is not an issue as we speak. I'm looking for people who already made the Maven + WLP setup for a developer workstation.

Comment: If I'm understanding the question I think it doesn't do what you are asking it to do, but I think it is a reasonable feature request which would require an issue in github. Although you may choose to interpret my 'I think' as me not knowing and therefore not being able to help you.